# Brownian Motion with stopping threshold

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate, finance

I just want to generate one stochastic process, whereas I want to be able to manipulate the start value and the volatility. Furthermore, the process should stop when it reaches 5

However, as soon as I use the SeedRandom[seed] function some error occurs.
Hope you can help me. 
I also want the function to start at 0 and not at 1
Definition function of:
(* x[t+1]=x[t]+μ (drift) + shock[t]; which stops at threshold*)

My code:

```
σ = 0.2
SeedRandom[85]; shock1 = 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ],(*time interval/Length of paths*) 10]

μ = 0.1 

 step[x_, μ_, shock1_] := 
 If[x == 5, 5, If[x + μ + shock1 < 5, 5, x + μ + shock1]]


p1 = FoldList[step, 10, shock1]

ListLogPlot[p1, Joined -> True]
```

This Works perfectly, however, as soon as I enter the following i get some Problems:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[seed]; 
 shock1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ1], 10]; μ =
   0.1; step[x_, μ_, shock1_] := 
  If[x == 5, 5, If[x + μ + shock1 < 5, 5, x + μ + shock1]]; 
 ListLogPlot[FoldList[step, S, shock1], Joined -> True], {S, 10, 
  50}, {σ1, 0.1, 1}]
```

I get the following error-message: "Argument seed in SeedRandom[seed] should be an integer or a string. "

But when I enter:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[85]; 
 shock1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ1], 10]; μ =
   0.1; step[x_, μ_, shock1_] := 
  If[x == 5, 5, If[x + μ + shock1 < 5, 5, x + μ + shock1]]; 
 ListLogPlot[FoldList[step, S, shock1], Joined -> True], {S, 10, 
  50}, {σ1, 0.1, 1}]
```

and try to manipulate the volatility just nothing happens.

do you have any solutions for my problem?

Comment: When you say that the first part works perfectly. It doesn't for me when I copy and paste that first section of code. If you quite the kernel, does the first part still work correctly?

Comment: The `Initialization` option might be useful here...

Comment: You might want to use `Clip` in place of the two nested `If`.

Comment: @Jonathan Shock I alos have your problem now. I do not know why. Although I enter Remove["Global`*"] before I enter everything. just before it worked, no other notebooks are open.

Comment: @MilanIvica What you mean exactly with "the process should stop when it reaches 5"? Value equal to 5? If yes, it depends on your starting value... Or do you mean time equal to 5? It's not clear IMO...

Comment: @Rod Lm I want the process to stop when: process <= 5.

Comment: @MilanIvica Value of process <=5, right?

Comment: @ Rod Lm for example. I have 10 processes which evolve under the following condition: x[t+1]=x[t] + μ (drift) + shock (GBM * σ (volatility)). And x[t] = 10. So all processes that fall below or equal 5 should stop, and all other should continue. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @MilanIvica It would be easier to simply generate a matrix of processes and then choose those which satisfy your condition, IMO.

Comment: @ Rod Lm Thanks. I will try to do this.

Comment: @MilanIvica I'm not sure if my last answer is also useful for this question... If yes, please tell me so I can put it as an answer...

Comment: @ Ron Lm are you referring to generating a matix of processes, if yes, I will try it tomorrow and post it here. thank you agian for your help

Comment: @Ron Lm Hi, you can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of details that make your function misbehave. Here is a version that takes in {currentx, mu} and a term of the `shock` list and outputs {newx, mu}. I changed your `If`s to a single `Which`. The manipulate now seems to work fine. I also moved the function definition outside the `Manipulate`, which is more efficient (there's no need to define the function at each pass through the `Manipulate`).

```
step[{x_, mu_}, s_] := {Which[x == 5, 5, x + mu + s > 5, 5, True, x + mu + s], mu};

Manipulate[sig = 0.2; mu = 0.05; len = 500; SeedRandom[seed]; start=1;
  shock = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sig], len];
  p1 = FoldList[step, {start, mu}, shock];
  ListLogPlot[p1[[All, 1]], Joined -> True], {seed, 1, 85, 1}]
```

[image]

There are a couple of subtleties in this problem. For instance, one of the comments to the OP suggested replacing the logic of the `Which` (or `If` in the OP) with `Clip`. This might not be a good idea because the goal is to freeze the process once it reaches 5. When clipping, the process might go above 5 (and be clipped) but later drop below 5 again. It is also more tricky than it seems to generate a lot of paths and then choose the ones you want: again, the paths would need to be processed to get the proper clipping.

Comment: thank you for your help an remarks